# Gravity Forms custom Field entry

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I've setup a pretty long form using gravity forms,  I have gravity custom fields installed and was hoping I could then create some custom fields using "Advanced custom fields" plugin.

Then once the fields were created,  associate fields in the form, to submit to one of those fields.

So ive setup My form field like this :

[image: https://imgur.com/a/kCDKl]

When submitting the form,  I expected it to fill out my custom field created in a custom post type here :

[image]

But instead,  as you can see the field is blank.  But scrolling down, to the custom field area.  The data is there :

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how the process works ? or does anyone have any insight please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are attempting to use the field key parameter which only means anything to ACF itself, it doesn't mean anything to the actual connection between Gravity Forms and the Custom Field property.  That's what the field name is before.  It's usually the lowercase, underscored version of your field title. "Business phone" becomes `business_phone` usually.

That's what you need to choose from the dropdown, or if it doesn't exist yet, just enter the field name under 'New' and as soon as GF saves it, it will switch to "Existing" with the field name in the dropdown.

Comment: Ah right,  The names were not there in the dropdown list which is why I thought the keys were what Gravity used.   So If i go and edit all the fields again with the titles it should work. 

Will go give it a try.

Comment: Thats perfect thank you,  Just to confirm, do I also need to keep the "insert merge tag" ?  I wasnt sure of the purpose of that. 

I will mark your answer as correct as soon as it lets me , apparently i can't do it in 3 mins :)

Comment: I don't think so?  I believe that's for the "content template" which could probably also be unchecked.  I'm unsure what you're using this for though, so...anyway, glad I could help!